# Find and shows the highest record of the name list

Tags: python

I'm new to Python.
I've been given a task to write a Python program to read a name list which consist of people names and their height.

Any suggestion or idea for coding to find out the highest height and show the record?

For examples, the highest height is 180 and the result will show "Adam,180"

Comment: Please show us your datasource

Comment: You got the task, not us. Please try to do it by yourself before you ask for a ready solution.

Comment: See `max` function, look at its `key` argument. See `operator.itemgetter`. Google both these and experiment, you'll learn more if you try it yourself :-).

Comment: You should do your own homework.

Comment: Thanks Jim, it helps :D

Answer (score 0):

We can use operator.itemgetter

```
import operator
stats = {'Dave':179, 'Adam':180, 'Daniel': 170}
max(stats.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: Thanks :D I would try dictionary later

Answer (score 0):

```
names = {'jason': 5.8, 'daniel': 5.0, 'rizwan': 6}

>>> sorted(names.items(), key=lambda value: value[1], reverse=True)
[('rizwan', 6), ('jason', 5.8), ('daniel', 5.0)]

>>> max(sorted(names.items(), key=lambda value: value[1]))
('rizwan', 6)
>>> min(sorted(names.items(), key=lambda value: value[1]))
('daniel', 5.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have separate lists:

```
names  =  ['alireza','sarah','maryam','muhammad']
heights = [180,172,178,182]
print(names[heights.index(max(heights))])
```

if you want use dictionary:

```
names = {'alireza':180,'sarah':172,'maryam':178,'muhammad':182}

max(names.keys(), key=names.get)
```

and if you want use 2d lists:

```
names = [['alireza',180],['sarah',172],['maryam',178],['muhammad',182]]
heights = list(zip(*names))[1]
print(names[heights.index(max(heights))][0])
```